# Derivative of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus

In a scientific paper, I've seen the following

$$\frac{\delta K^{-1}}{\delta p} = -K^{-1}\frac{\delta K}{\delta p}K^{-1}$$

where $K$ is a $n \times n$ matrix that depends on $p$. In my calculations I would have done the following

$$\frac{\delta K^{-1}}{\delta p} = -K^{-2}\frac{\delta K}{\delta p}=-K^{-T}K^{-1}\frac{\delta K}{\delta p}$$

Is my calculation wrong?

Note: I think $K$ is symmetric.

Comment: It is wrong. Note: matrices do not commute in general. Respect the order when derivate.

Comment: Hint:$ \partial_{\rho}(KK^{-1})=\partial_{\rho}\mathbb{1}$

Comment: @tired what is $\mathbb{1}$? Do you perhaps mean $I$?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The major trouble in matrix calculus is that the things are no longer commuting, but one tends to use formulae from the scalar function calculus like $(x(t)^{-1})'=-x(t)^{-2}x'(t)$ replacing $x$ with the matrix $K$. **One has to be more careful here and pay attention to the order**. The easiest way to get the derivative of the inverse is to derivate the identity $I=KK^{-1}$ *respecting the order*
$$
\underbrace{(I)'}_{=0}=(KK^{-1})'=K'K^{-1}+K(K^{-1})'.
$$
Solving this equation with respect to $(K^{-1})'$ (again paying attention to the order (!)) will give
$$
K(K^{-1})'=-K'K^{-1}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad (K^{-1})'=-K^{-1}K'K^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Looks like this also holds for total derivative with p being any parameter set, following the same derivation

Answer (score 24):

Yes, your calculation is wrong, note that $K$ may not commute with $\frac{\partial K}{\partial p}$, hence you must apply the chain rule correctly. The derivative of $\def\inv{\mathrm{inv}}\inv \colon \def\G{\mathord{\rm GL}}\G_n \to \G_n$ is **not** given by $\inv'(A)B = -A^2B$, but by $\inv'(A)B = -A^{-1}BA^{-1}$. To see that, note that for small enough $B$ we have 
\begin{align*}
  \inv(A + B) &= (A + B)^{-1}\\
              &= (\def\I{\mathord{\rm Id}}\I + A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}\\
              &= \sum_k (-1)^k (A^{-1}B)^kA^{-1}\\
              &= A^{-1} - A^{-1}BA^{-1} + o(\|B\|) 
\end{align*}
Hence, $\inv'(A)B= -A^{-1}BA^{-1}$, and therefore, by the chain rule 
$$ \partial_p (\inv \circ K) = \inv'\circ K\bigl(\partial_p K) = -K^{-1}(\partial_p K) K^{-1} $$

Comment: How does the second line follow from B being small enough?

Comment: @nbubis The Neumann series is $I - A = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} A^k$ for $\| A \| < 1$, which is analogous to the geometric series. Thus for small enough $B$ we have $\| A^{-1} B \| < 1$ and thus $(I + A^{-1} B)^{-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (A^{-k} B)^k$.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, we can directly calculate the derivate of a matrix starting from the definition of the derivate of functions. In particular,
\begin{align}
\frac{dK^{-1}}{dp} & =\lim_{\Delta p \to 0} \frac{(K+\Delta K)^{-1} - K^{-1}}{\Delta p} \\
{} & = \lim_{\Delta p \to 0} \frac{(K+\Delta K)^{-1}KK^{-1} - (K+\Delta K)^{-1}(K+\Delta K)K^{-1}}{\Delta p}  \\ 
{} & = \lim_{\Delta p \to 0} \frac{(K+\Delta K)^{-1}(-\Delta K) K^{-1}}{\Delta p} \\ 
{} & = - K^{-1} \lim_{\Delta p \to 0} \frac{\Delta K}{\Delta p} K^{-1}  \\ 
{} & = - K^{-1} (\partial_{p} K) K^{-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Another related method is to use differentials.
$$
d\mathbf{K}^{-1}=
-\mathbf{K}^{-1} (d\mathbf{K}) \mathbf{K}^{-1}
$$
and $d\mathbf{K}=
\frac{\partial \mathbf{K}}{\partial p} dp$
Thus
$$
d\mathbf{K}^{-1}=
-\left[\mathbf{K}^{-1} \frac{\partial \mathbf{K}}{\partial p} \mathbf{K}^{-1} \right] dp
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{K}^{-1}}{\partial p}
=
-\mathbf{K}^{-1} \frac{\partial \mathbf{K}}{\partial p} \mathbf{K}^{-1} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

given a square matrix K, we have

\begin{align}
KK^{-1} &= I \\
\implies \frac{d(KK^{-1})}{dp} &=\frac{d(I)}{dp}\\
\end{align}
for notational simplicity, we use $dK = \frac{dK}{dp}$, thus
\begin{align}
(dK)K^{-1} + K(dK^{-1})&=0\\
\implies K(dK^{-1})&= -(dK)K^{-1}\\
\implies dK^{-1}&= -K^{-1}(dK)K^{-1}\\
\end{align}

which yileds:
$$\frac{dK^{-1}}{dp}= -K^{-1}\frac{dK}{dp}K^{-1}$$