# How to calculate $\dfrac{\partial a^{\rm T}A^{-\rm T}bb^{\rm T}A^{-1}a}{\partial A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

How can I calculate $\dfrac{\partial a^{\rm T}A^{-\rm T}bb^{\rm T}A^{-1}a}{\partial A}$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I just finished your previous problem... Why add another b?

Comment: @JiaqiLi Sorry about that. Could you possibly modify your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Name $\phi_1 : A \mapsto A^{-1}$, $\phi_2 : A \mapsto b^T A a$ and $\phi_3: A \mapsto A^T A$. Note that your map $\phi$ is $\phi = \phi_3 \circ \phi_2 \circ \phi_1$.

You can then use the chain rule $\phi^\prime = \phi_3^\prime \cdot \phi_2^\prime \cdot \phi_1^\prime$, based on $\phi_1^\prime(A).H =-A^{-1}HA^{-1}$, $\phi_2^\prime(A).H = b^T H a$ and $\phi_3^\prime(A).H = 2A^T H$.

You’ll finally get:

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A}.H = -2 (b^TA^{-1}a)^Tb^TA^{-1}HA^{-1}a =-2a^T\left(A^{-1}\right)^T bb^T A^{-1}HA^{-1}a$$

Comment: Since the final result is a second-order tensor, how could we transform the result to a matrix form (without using the increment $H$)?

Comment: @JiaqiLi You can’t do that. The reason is that a linear application between matrices spaces isn’t always of the form $H \mapsto AH$. This is the case here. The reason is that matrices are not always commuting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was just modified. If there is b (as now), then the solution would be much simpler. Note that 
$$a^{\rm T}A^{-\rm T}b = b^{\rm T}A^{-1}a$$
since they are numbers and transposing one of them would give you the other. Hence from chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A}(a^{\rm T}A^{-\rm T}bb^{\rm T}A^{-1}a)=2(b^{\rm T}A^{-1}a)\frac{\partial}{\partial A}(b^{\rm T}A^{-1}a)$$
Also note that when we take derivative with respect to $A$, both $a$ and $b$ are treated as constants. Then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A}(b^{\rm T}A^{-1}a)=b^{\rm T}\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}a$$
Finally it remains to calculate $\partial A^{-1}/\partial A$. From the identity
$$AA^{-1} = I$$
taking derivative with respect to $A$, we obtain
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A}(AA^{-1})=IA^{-1}+A\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}=0$$
Thus
$$\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}=-A^{-2}.$$

Comment: The equality $\frac{\partial}{\partial A}(AA^{-1})=IA^{-1}+A\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}=0$ isn’t correct. The issue which isn’t easy to understand is that $\frac{\partial A}{\partial A}$ isn’t the matrix $I$ but the identity. And $\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}.H = -A^{-1}HA^{-1}$ not $-A{-2}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix for more details.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. Could you explain how do we calculate $\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}.H = -A^{-1}HA^{-1}$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I've looked at the link you provided, but I still have trouble understanding the derivative when the independent variable is a matrix (2nd order tensor).

Comment: What is important to understand is for an internal application $f$ of the matrices spaces, the derivative is an application from the matrices space into the linear applications between the matrices space. Apart from that the link I provided is pretty explicit on the computation of the derivative of $A \mapsto A^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\B{A^{-T}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Use a colon to denote the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$

Introduce the scalar variable
$$\eqalign{
\l \;=\; {a^T\B b}
   \;=\; {b^T\A a}
   \;=\; {ba^T:\A}
}$$
whose differential is
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= {ba^T:\c{d\A}} \\
 &= ba^T:\c{\LR{-\A\;dA\;\A}} \\
 &= -\LR{\B ba^T\B}:dA \\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to write the function, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \l^2 \\
df &= 2\l\;\c{d\l} \\
 &= -2\l \c{\LR{\B ba^T\B}:dA} \\
\grad{f}{A}
 &= -2\l \LR{\B ba^T\B} \\
 &= -2 \LR{b^T\A a} \LR{\B ba^T\B} \\\\
}$$