# Differentiation of solution to time-dependent system of equations: Problem 2-15(c) from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

This is Problem 2-15(c) from Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*.

> **Problem 2-15(c).** If $\det(a_{ij}(t)) \neq 0$ for all $t$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable, let $s_1,\dots,s_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the functions such that $s_1(t),\dots,s_n(t)$ are the solutions of the equations
>   $$
> \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}(t) s_j(t) = b_i(t) \qquad i = 1,\dots,n.
> $$
>   Show that $s_i$ is differentiable and find ${s_i}'(t)$.

It is also given (in part (b) of the same problem) that the $a_{ij}$'s are taken to be differentiable.

I am presenting my solution below, followed by my question.

---

Let $A(t) = (a_{ij}(t))$ be an $n \times n$ matrix for each $t$. Then, the given system of equations corresponds to
$$
S(t) A(t) = B(t),
$$
where $$S(t) = \begin{bmatrix} s_1(t) & \cdots & s_n(t) \end{bmatrix}$$ and
$$B(t) = \begin{bmatrix} b_1(t) & \cdots & b_n(t) \end{bmatrix}.$$ Let
$$
A_i(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t) \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
b_1(t) & \cdots & b_n(t) \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the $b_i$'s are inserted in the $i$th row.
Then, by Cramer's Rule,
$$
s_i(t) = \frac{\det A_i(t)}{\det A(t)}.
$$
Problem 2-15(b) shows that $\det A_i(t)$ and $\det A(t)$ are differentiable, and so $s_i$ is differentiable for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. To compute ${s_i}'(t)$ we can use the chain rule. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

My problem is that after applying the chain rule, I get a huge ugly expression with no means of simplifying it in sight. It doesn't look like the functions ${s_i}'(t)$ have any natural interpretation.

Now, I wouldn't put it past Spivak to ask the student to perform a lengthy calculation just for the sake of it (after all, that's what Problem 2-10 was all about). But I still can't help but feel I'm missing something here. Especially since he asks us to redo the computation later (Problem 2-40) using the Implicit Function Theorem.

Can anyone tell me if I'm proceeding in the right direction, or if there is another (perhaps more illuminating) way to solve this problem?

---

I'm stating Problem 2-15(b) below for completeness.

> **Problem 2-15(b).** If $a_{ij} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable and $f(t) = \det(a_{ij}(t))$, show that
>   $$
> f'(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n \det
> \begin{bmatrix}
> a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
> \vdots &  & \vdots \\
> {a_{j1}}'(t) & \cdots & {a_{jn}}'(t) \\
> \vdots &  & \vdots \\
> a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use vector / matrix notation.

You have

$$S(t)=\left(A(t)\right)^{-1}.B(t)$$

Knowing that $\left(A^{-1}\right)^\prime(t)=-A^{-1}(t) A^\prime(t) A^{-1}(t)$ you get

$$S^\prime(t)=-A^{-1}(t) A^\prime(t) A^{-1}(t)B(t) +A^{-1}(t)B^\prime(t)=A^{-1}(t)\left(-A^\prime(t)S(t)+B^\prime(t)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! How can we show that $(A^{-1})'(t) = -A^{-1}(t)A'(t)A^{-1}(t)$?

Comment: Oh wait, we can write $I = AA^{-1}$ and then use the chain rule?

Comment: Yes see [derivative of matrix inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to simplify the expression for ${s_i}'(t)$ into something reasonable. I am posting my work here as an answer. Again, any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Let $f,g_1,\dots,g_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(t) = \det A(t)$ and $g_i(t) = \det A_i(t)$. Then,
$$
s_i(t) = \frac{g_i(t)}{f(t)},
$$
so by the chain rule we have
$$
\begin{align}
{s_i}'(t) &= \frac{f(t) {g_i}'(t) - g_i(t) f'(t)}{f(t)^2}\\
&= \frac{f(t) {g_i}'(t) - s_i(t) f(t) f'(t)}{f(t)^2}\\
&= \frac{{g_i}'(t) - s_i(t) f'(t)}{f(t)}.
\end{align}
$$
Now, we observe that
$$
{g_i}'(t) = \sum_{\substack{j = 1\\j \neq i}}^n \det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
{a_{j1}}'(t) & \cdots & {a_{jn}}'(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
b_1(t) & \cdots & b_n(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix}
+\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
{b_1}'(t) & \cdots & {b_n}'(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
s_i(t) f'(t) = \sum_{\substack{j = 1\\j \neq i}}^n \det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
{a_{j1}}'(t) & \cdots & {a_{jn}}'(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
s_i(t) a_{i1}(t) & \cdots & s_i(t)a_{in}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix} + \det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
s_i(t) {a_{i1}}'(t) & \cdots & s_i(t){a_{in}}'(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix},
$$
because $s_i(t)$ is a scalar and so can be multiplied into any one row
or column of a determinant, and in particular the $i$th row as we have done here. Hence,
$$
{s_i}'(t) = \frac{h(t)}{f(t)}
$$
where
$$
h(t) = \sum_{\substack{j=1\\ j \neq i}}^n \det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
{a_{j1}}'(t) & \cdots & {a_{jn}}'(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
b_1(t)-s_i(t)a_{i1}(t) & \cdots & b_n(t)-s_i(t)a_{in}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix}+\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
{b_1}'(t) - s_i(t) {a_{i1}}'(t) & \cdots & {b_n}'(t) - s_i(t){a_{in}}'(t)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1}(t) & \cdots & a_{nn}(t)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

Again, any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.