# Derivative of matrix-valued function and chain rule

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, tensors, chain-rule

I have a function $\Gamma(x): \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n \times m}$ defined as
$$
\Gamma(x) :=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11}(x) & X_{12}(x) \\
X_{21}(x) & X_{22}(x)
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
B
$$
where $B \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times m}$ is constant and $X_{ij}(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. How can I find $\Gamma^{\prime}(x)$? I'm trying to use the chain rule and Cramer's rule for the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Definition)  but am stuck.

In particular, I define
$$
X(x) := 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11}(x) & X_{12}(x) \\
X_{21}(x) & X_{22}(x)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}X}\Gamma = -(X^{-1}B)^{\top} \otimes X^{-1}$$
but I am confused about pushing the chain rule through for $$\frac{{\rm d}X}{{\rm d}x}.$$

What I'm trying to do is something like:
\begin{align}
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x} \Gamma &= \frac{{\rm d}\Gamma}{{\rm d}X} \cdot  \frac{{\rm d}X}{{\rm d}x} \\
&= \left( -(X^{-1}B)^{\top} \otimes X^{-1} \right) \cdot \frac{{\rm d}X}{{\rm d}x}
\end{align}
but am unsure of what sort of product "$\cdot$" denotes here. Differentiatiating entry-by-entry of $x$ as
$$
{\rm vec} \left( \frac{{\rm d}\Gamma}{{\rm d}x_i}(x) \right) = (B^{\top} \otimes I_n) \cdot {\rm vec}\left( X^{-1}(x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}X(x) \cdot X^{-1}(x) \right)
$$
and then stacking the resulting vectors horizontally to gives $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x} \Gamma$, but I'm not sure how to represent this object more compactly via tensors / Krons / Frobenius inner products. Is
$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x} \Gamma = \left( -(X^{-1}B)^{\top} \otimes X^{-1} \right) : \frac{{\rm d}X}{{\rm d}x}
$$
right? Would it be easier to use tensor notation?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: thanks, didn't see this! Trying now

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the derivative in vector form it becomes clearer.
$$
\mathrm{vec}(\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma)=\mathrm{vec}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (X^{-1} B)) = -(X^{-1}B)^\top \otimes X^{-1} \mathrm{vec}(\Gamma'(x)) $$

Now using $$(A\otimes B)\mathrm{vec}(C) = \mathrm{vec}(BCA^T)$$ we get

$$
\mathrm{vec}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\Gamma B)) = - \mathrm{X^{-1}\Gamma'(x)X^{-1}}B
$$

Comment: thanks, and am I correct that this also assumes $x$ is scalar?

Comment: If x is not scalar the result will no longer be a matrix.  If x is a matrix then the derivative $\Gamma'(x)$ would have the same size as your kronecker product and you would have to vec the Kronecker product as well to use the chain rule.

Comment: Btw, is $Y$ in your second display $C$?

Comment: Would you mind explaining vec-ing the Kronecker product and using the chain rule in more detail in the case where $x$ is a vector?

Comment: Sorry Y should have been C. I made a correction.

Comment: Why do you start by computing $\mathrm{vec}(\frac{\partial}{\partial X} (\Gamma B))$? Don't we want $\mathrm{vec}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\Gamma))$?

Comment: More errors on my part.  I corrected it now.

Comment: But I think you compute derivative wrt $X$? Whereas I'm seeking wrt $x$

Comment: That's another type.  I wrote d/dX, but calculated d/dx

Answer (score 0):

For ease of typing, use a dot to denote the derivative wrt the scalar parameter, e.g. 
$$\dot F = \frac{dF}{dx}$$
Now consider the derivative of a matrix inverse.
$$\eqalign{
I &= XY \quad&\implies\quad Y = X^{-1} \\
\dot I &= \dot XY + X\dot Y \\
0 &= \dot XY + X\dot Y \quad&\implies\quad \dot Y = -Y\dot XY \\
}$$
Applying this to the current problem yields
$$\eqalign{
\Gamma &= X^{-1}B = YB \\
\dot\Gamma &= \dot YB = -Y\dot XYB = -X^{-1}\dot X\,\Gamma \\
}$$