# Metric tensor derivative identity

Tags: matrices, tensors

In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0009250960870030), the following identity is used without proof nor reference:

$$g^{\alpha \mu} g^{\beta \lambda} \dot{g}_{\alpha \beta} \equiv -\dot{g}^{\mu \lambda}$$

where $g$ is metric tensor and $\dot{g}$ is derivative of $g$.

How can this identity derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is from the matrix identity,
$$\partial X^{-1} = - X^{-1} (\partial X) X^{-1}$$

Proof for this identity is in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix).

With this, we have
$$X (\partial X^{-1}) X = - \partial X$$

By substituting $X$ with $g^{\mu \lambda}$, we get the identity!