# backprobagation of linear solve

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, linear-programming, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to figure out why the derivative of the solve operation is [this](https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ChainRules.jl/blob/b92da5068b6d614d2a3a4fa4063233640135775c/src/rulesets/LinearAlgebra/structured.jl#L18) in the chainrule package. After reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix) i started writing this but i can't seems to get past what i've written.

i know that we have
$$
Ax=b\\
x=A\backslash b\\
x = A^{-1}b
$$

futhermore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A_{ij}} &= 
\sum_k\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial A_{ij}}\\
\end{align}
$$

where $L$ is the loss(a function of x). Let $c_k$ be $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_k}$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A_{ij}} &= 
\sum_k c_k\frac{\partial (A^{-1}b)_k}{\partial A_{ij}}\\
&= c^\top \frac{\partial A^{-1}b}{\partial A_{ij}}\\
&= c^\top \left(\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A_{ij}} b + A^{-1}\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}}\right) \\
&= c^\top \left(-A^{-1}\frac{\partial A}{\partial A_{ij}}A^{-1} b + A^{-1}\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}}\right) \\
&= c^\top \left(-A^{-1}1_{ij}x + A^{-1}\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}}\right) \\
&= c^\top \left(A^{-1}(\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}} - 1_{ij}x)\right) \\
\end{align}
$$
where $1_ij$ is matrix whose $ij$ th cell is one(the others are zero).

The thing i'm missing here is how can we calculate $\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}}$ in the backprob since we can't know it.

--edit--

for the sake of completeness Chainrule.jl uses
$$
\partial A = -(A') ^{-1} c  x'\\
\partial b = A' \ c
$$
where $'$ is the conjugate transpose

Comment: Assuming $b$ is independent of $A$, isn't $\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}}=0$?

Comment: that's the thing, it doesn't have to be you could have something like x = A \ diag(A), it should still hold. in the code they have a general solution for this

Comment: What's the problem? If $\,b={\rm diag}(A)\,$ then in your notation 
$\,\frac{\partial b}{\partial A_{ij}}={\rm diag}({\tt1}_{ij})$

Comment: this rule can't be used in a back propagation.