# Derivative involving inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, inverse, matrix-calculus

Let $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ for all $i\in[k]$, with $k \geq d$. I am looking for this derivative

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha_i} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_ix_ix_i^T\right)^{-1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha_i} \left(X\Lambda X^\top\right)^{-1},
$$

where we define $X: \text{col(X)}= \{x_i\}_{i\in[k]}$, $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\alpha)$, and we assume $\left(X\Lambda X^\top\right)$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes, defining $G(\alpha) = \left(X\Lambda X^\top\right)$, if $h \neq \alpha_i$,  for all $i$, we have that $G(\alpha-h)$ is full rank and hence its inverse exist. But I don't see how to proceed from here to find the derivative.

Comment: The matrix has rank at most $k$ (its image is contained in the span of ${x_i}$), thus for $k<d$ the matrix cannot be invertible.

Comment: You are right! updated the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call $A=X\Lambda X^T$. Now, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha_i}A^{-1} = -A^{-1} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha_i} A \right)A^{-1}$$ (see [Derivative of the inverse of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix)), provided $A^{-1}$ exists. Finally, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha_i} A= x_i x_i^T$$.

Comment: Thanks @lisyarus. Can we also claim that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}A^{-1} = -A^{-1} XX^TA^{-1}$

Comment: @temporary_freak I don't think so: the derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector has to be a third-order tensor, not just a matrix. The derivative of a matrix with respect to a *scalar* is already a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Given fat matrix ${\rm V} \in \Bbb R^{d \times n}$, let

$${\rm F} ({\rm x}) := {\rm V} \,\mbox{diag} ({\rm x}) {\rm V}^\top, \qquad {\rm G} ({\rm x}) := \left( {\rm F} ({\rm x}) \right)^{-1}$$

Using [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula),

$$\begin{aligned} {\rm G} ({\rm x} + h \, {\rm e}_i) = \left( {\rm F} ({\rm x} + h \, {\rm e}_i) \right)^{-1} = \left( {\rm F} ({\rm x}) + h \, {\rm v}_i {\rm v}_i^\top \right)^{-1} &= {\rm G} ({\rm x}) - h \,\frac{{\rm G} ({\rm x}) \, {\rm v}_i {\rm v}_i^\top {\rm G} ({\rm x})}{1 + h \, {\rm v}_i^\top {\rm F} ({\rm x}) \,{\rm v}_i} \\ &= {\rm G} ({\rm x}) - h \,{\rm G} ({\rm x}) \, {\rm v}_i {\rm v}_i^\top {\rm G} ({\rm x}) + \mathcal O \left( h^2 \right)\end{aligned}$$

and, thus,

$$\partial_i {\rm G} ({\rm x}) = \color{blue}{- {\rm G} ({\rm x}) \, {\rm v}_i {\rm v}_i^\top {\rm G} ({\rm x})}$$

which is what Господин Лисица [obtained](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4074291/339790).

---

[matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [matrix-calculus](/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) [derivatives](/questions/tagged/derivatives)

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo. It's a shame I cannot accept both answers!