# Inverse matrix derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}, b\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times 1},$ and $\Lambda\triangleq\text{diag}(\lambda),$ where $\lambda\triangleq[\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_M]$.

I would need to compute the following derivative: $$\frac{d}{d\lambda}[(A^\text{T}A+\Lambda)^{-1}A^\text{T}B].$$

I worked on it and I got this, $\forall i=1,\ldots,M$:$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda_i}[(A^\text{T}A+\Lambda)^{-1}A^\text{T}B]=$$$$(A^\text{T}A+\Lambda)^{-1}E_i(A^\text{T}A+\Lambda)^{-1}A^{T}B,$$
where $E_i$ is a matrix with all $0$'s except the $i$th diagonal element which is equal to 1.

Is this correct? I feel like something is missing or incorrect.

Comment: It seems correct to me if $A$ and $B$ are independent of $\lambda_i$. Why do you think it is incorrect? And if you provide the steps of your work someone can pinpoint the error if there is one.

Comment: Definitely correct, see that related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\l{\lambda}\def\L{\Lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$It's difficult to visually distinguish $\L$ from $A$, so I'll
rename $\,\L\to L.$

The gradient of a vector with respect to one of its components is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\l}{\l_k} &= \e_k
}$$
where $\e_k$ is the $k^{th}$ standard basis vector.

Use this to calculate
$$\eqalign{
\grad{L}{\l_k} = \grad{\Diag\l}{\l_k} = \Diag{\e_k} \\\\
}$$

Define the following matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
E_k &= \Diag{\e_k} \\
M &= \LR{A^TA+L} &\qiq dM &= dL \\
W &= M^{-1}  &\qiq dW &= -W\,dL\,W \\
}$$
and substitute them into the function of interest
$$\eqalign{
 F &= WA^TB \\
dF &= dW\,A^TB \\
 &= -W\,dL\,WA^TB \\
 &= -W\,dL\,F \\
\grad{F}{\l_k} &= -W\gradLR{L}{\l_k}F \\
 &= -WE_kF \\
}$$
which confirms your own result.